# Does VSCODE.window.showInputBox provide a means to reject the input with a message and reprompt?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible using `vscode.window.showInputBox` to allow validation on the data entered and return an error message and reprompt?

Or do I have to use `vscode.window.CreateInputBox` and show/dispose   onDidHide/ onDidAccept to provide this ability?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code:

```js
  vscode.window.showInputBox({
    placeHolder: "howdy there",
    validateInput: text => {
      vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`Validating: ${text}`);  // you don't need this
      return text === '123' ? null : 'Not 123!';  // return null if validates
  }});
```

> Return undefined, null, or the empty string when 'value' is valid.

[image: inputBox validate demo]

So it doesn't re-prompt with a new inputBox but shows a message in red when the input does not validate.

The user cannot <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept invalid input, the user can only <kbd>Escape</kbd> to dispose of the InputBox.

You could `vscode.window.showInformationMessage` as part of the invalid process, something like:

```js
vscode.window.showInputBox({
    placeHolder: "howdy there",
    validateInput: text => {
            // vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`Validating: ${text}`);
      if (text === '123') return null;
      else {
        if (text !== '') vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`Invalid: ${ text }.  Should be of form...`);
        return 'Not 123!';
      }
            // return text === '123' ? null : 'Not 123!';
  }});
```

But the input is evaluated on each character input which is cumbersome.

see, e.g., https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/quickinput-sample/src/basicInput.ts or https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42763#issue-293656558