# How can I wrap selected code with a copied or pre-determined function in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The workflow in Visual Studio code would be improved if there was
a shortcut, with which I can wrap selected code with a function
(e.g. the selected code becomes the argument of some function

```
"delta" -> somefunction("delta")
```

The name of the function could be given by a dialog window.

I did not find an extension for that (Python code). Is there an efficient way to add this to shortcuts?

An idea for a keyboard short-cut is this

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+j",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      // to do:
      "vscode.window.showInputBox()", // show dialog box
      // combine the editor.selection and dialog box response as response + "(" + editor.selection + ")"
      // Delete editor selection and insert the combination instead 
    ]
  }
},
```

---

Further Sources:

- [Dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65999892/does-vscode-window-showinputbox-provide-a-means-to-reject-the-input-with-a-messa) and [Custom Dialog Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481386/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-in-vscode)

Comment: you can write a snippet with the `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}` variable, select the text, immediately type the snippet prefix and type TAB

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Refactoring guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_refactoring) on the Visual Studio Code documentation site. Is this working for you?

> #### Refactoring
>
> The Python extension adds the following refactoring functionalities: **Extract Variable**, **Extract Method** and **Rename Module**. It also supports extensions that implement additional refactoring features such as **Sort Imports**.
>
> ##### Extract Variable:
>
> Extracts all similar occurrences of the selected text within the current scope, and replaces it with a new variable.
>
> You can invoke this command by selecting the line of code you wish to extract as a variable. Then select the light-bulb that is displayed next to it.

You can make use of this feature by following these steps:

1. Select code you want to extract
2. On the left side of the selection, a yellow light bulb will appear (if it does not appear, click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>), click on in it.
3. There will be "Extract method" and "Extract variable" options. Click on "Extract method".

I have the **Python** and **Pylance** extensions installed.

Comment: When I clicked on it, re-trying for an entire minute, VS Code's site, or at least that page, was down for some internal maintenance or other issue and I got a custom error screen. I have edited the post to include some additional relevant information.

Comment: Hey Milos, that is a great hint, but is that not the inverse operation? It looks like, they extract/define a new variable when functions are chained. I would be rather interested in selecting a variable and build the function around the selection.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I didn't really got what you were saying. I can't seem to find extension or feature that can do that. 
@Tyler sorry for not formatting answer as it should be. Wanted to get it out as soon as possible and reformat it if helpful.

Comment: Your idea of extracting a method is great for more complex situations, in which a new function needs to be defined for a whole code block.